# An error occurs when adding a container command to Django aws eb

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using Python 3.7 Django 3.0.9 postgresql 11

-ebextension/django.config

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_compilemessages:
    command: "django-admin.py compilemessages"

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: config.wsgi:application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: config.settings
```

Error message when running eb deploy

```
2020-08-04 14:48:51    INFO    Environment update is starting.
2020-08-04 14:49:30    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2020-08-04 14:49:45    ERROR   [Instance: i-0719a2ed67b621907] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].
2020-08-04 14:49:45    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-08-04 14:49:45    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0719a2ed67b621907'. Aborting the operation.
2020-08-04 14:49:45    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.
```

eb logs error content

```
2020/08/04 11:35:55.132182 ERROR Requirements file provided! Importing into Pipfile…
2020/08/04 11:35:56.227858 ERROR Error occurred during build: Command 01_migrate failed
2020/08/04 11:35:56.227884 ERROR An error occurred during execution of command app-deploy - PostBuildEbExtension. Stop running the command. Error: Container commands build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.
```

After checking the command 01_migrate failed message,
it seems that there is a problem with the continer commands, so I ran django-admin migrate.

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
> DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the
> environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I have defined environment variables in django.config, but there is an error, I cannot deploy my site
django-admin migrate is replaced by python manage.py migrate but still doesn't deploy
You can also find the detailed code on my GitHub

https://github.com/dopza86/air_bnb_clone

I don't know how to do it, I need your help,thank you

Answer (score 0):

When your `container_commands` command run, you won't be in your python's environment. Also make sure that env variables are set before your `container_commands` run.

For this you can modify your `.ebextentions`:

**01-env_var.config**

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: config.wsgi:application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: config.settings
```

**05-packages.config**

```
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql-devel: []
```

**10-django.config**

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: |
      env # just to print out the env variables for checking in logs
      source $PYTHONPATH/activate
      django-admin.py migrate
    leader_only: true
  02_compilemessages:
    command: |
      env # just to print out the env variables for checking in logs
      source $PYTHONPATH/activate
      django-admin.py compilemessages
```

Comment: I solved the problem by referring to the question, always be happy

Answer (score 0):

It seems like AWS has changed the way to customize the nginx reverse proxy and buried the documentation deep:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html

In short, instead of using `.ebextensions` with a `files:` directive, one needs to create a nested path: `.platform > .nginf > conf.d`, and place there the nginx customization `.conf` files.